# PHPGuard - PHP source code encryption

Tags: php, encryption, obfuscation

My company is concerned about our PHP code being stolen by another company with access to the same server, so they purchased PHPGuard (phpguard.net).

After encrypting the files or folder it just creates a .prot files/folder and the source stays there. If the source is deleted, then the code won't be executed (obviously). This software doesn't come with any tool to execute the encrypted code, so I wonder how will this work at all.

I am starting to think this is just a scam, is anyone using this? How it is supposed to work?

PS: I know this is not a programming question but I am in a very bad fix now having to deploy to the server with my company concerns about the code being stolen...

Comment: The website looks like scam to me, I can't even find their email address or phone number on it.

Comment: @AgreeOrNot I think I need to agree with you. Sadly not much can be done now about it and I am stuck between an urgent deployment and my boss worries and stinginess T_T

Comment: To be honest, if the code is not precious enough to be worth hosting on a dedicated server then it probably isn't worth trying to steal it. Dedicated servers are not expensive and have higher performance.  Note that as has been stated here many times, if your computer can run it, someone clever can steal it.

Comment: @RobertSeddon-Smith while I agree with you, sadly, most of us work for bosses who have/impose their own views. This is actually a dedicated server but we are 2 companies working on different components for the same project, hence my boss paranoia on the other company taking our code and deleting us from this project equation lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I turned out it seems this PHPGuard is not a scam, but it is not working at all.

I did a simple test on a PHP 5.4 server:
info.php

```
<?php

phpinfo();

?>
```

info.prot.php

```
<?php $_F=__FILE__;$_C1808890765='P0U1P29+bzMzb35veVBkMiZ6azMzP0U=';$_D=strrev('edoced_46esab');
eval($_D('JF9DMTgwODg5MDc2NT1iYXNlNjRfZGVjb2RlKCRfQzE4MDg4OTA3NjUpOyRfQzE4MDg4OTA3NjU9c3Ryd
HIoJF9DMTgwODg5MDc2NSwnCUE7DVE+bmEpczJ1YigqQklve1hEZ35HVwpSNXI/VQBKM1pOODBFaWs3amNfJTEhdkh6
LHdNS3lbXS1ZFWRsYH09RmgmL1N0QzxWZkw2cDo5ZW1QNHEueCtPI1QnLCcsQXlXT3czdC8tb0x6SXUJKnA1LmNGaGU
xUzg8Ug17FToKX2RKQj5HOz8wWwByVWJaZykrNFFgaWslN302ZlAjfks9RChqc0gyTXZxJlZUYV1OQ25FWWw5IW14WC
cpOyRfUj1zdHJfcmVwbGFjZSgnX19GSUxFX18nLCInIi4kX0YuIiciLCRfQzE4MDg4OTA3NjUpO2V2YWwoJF9SKTskX
1I9MDskX0MxODA4ODkwNzY1PTA7'));?>
```

PHP error log

```
PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '>' in /Dev/Projects/Gateway/info.prot.php(1) : eval()'d code(5) : eval()'d code on line 2
```

I don't think it can get simpler than that :-P

Anyway, they claim the code is not recoverable which is plain BS. In my limited understanding this is just an obfuscation (more advanced than just changing variable and function names, but also slower). Also, the tool is a Windows exe that should not be too hard to reverse engineer to see how it's actually creating the encoded strings.

Well, at least support contacted me back and now I show them this test. I guess they will get back saying PHP 5.4 is not compatible or something on those terms.

PS: You get what you pay for, 60USD for a crappy obfuscator that doesn't work. So, if you really want to encode your source I would go with an established solution like Zend or Semantic Designs(maybe even try the Facebook hiphop thing if you are on a UNIX). At the end I didn't listen to my boss and deployed the ol'plain source code :-P

PS2: I really love the `strrev('edoced_46esab')` part, completely undecodable :-D